# Unable to install system images for the Android SDK: "Failed to create directory"

Tags: android-emulator, android-sdk, emulators

I've just installed Xamarin, to use C# on Android: on their tutorial about how to install the emulator [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment%2C_testing%2C_and_metrics/configuring_the_x86_emulator). I saw they installed Intel x86 Atom system image and ARM v7a system image, so I did the same and got this with both API 18 and 15, but only ARM vt7a (15) was successfully installed

> Downloading ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 18, revision 2
>
> Installing ARM ABIv7a System Image, Android API 18, revision 2
>
> Failed to create directory C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk-windows/system-images/android-18/armeabi-v7a
>
> Downloading Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 18, revision 1
>
> Installing Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 18, revision 1
>
> Failed to create directory C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk-windows/system-images/android-18/x86Done.
>
> Nothing was installed.

I'm on win 8, 64-bit, do you think the problem is my laptop architecture?

Comment: Looks like an access right problem to me. Are you administrator on your box?

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker: do you mean computer? if yes, yes, I am an administrator

Comment: Yes, your PC. *Failed to create directory C:/Pr...* looks like the SDK isn't allowed to write to this place

Comment: you are right: i had to "run as administrator" SDK manager, it's a windows8 issue that I really hate

Comment: Posted this as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK needs to be **run as admistrator** to be able to write those files.

Just retry and run it with elevated rights.